# How to monitor the container in Docker?

Tags: docker, containers, checkpoint

For example, if I want to know details of operation on containers like `docker checkpoint` command and how it prepares the information and dumps them, which tool is helpful(maybe like `GDB`)? If someone has the experience of monitoring and debugging it, please give me some advice or some tutorials.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/

Answer (score 0):

`GDB` is a great tool to debug. But if you really like to know in details then try **docker development environment**. You can hack the Docker source code and it's pretty fun.

How to set up Docker development**strong text** environment :

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/docs/contributing/set-up-dev-env.md

Docker **source code** :

https://github.com/moby/moby

Docker **checkpoint code** can be found here

All the **routes from the Docker API server** related to checkpoint can be found here :
https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/api/server/router/checkpoint/checkpoint_routes.go

Here is the Docker code to create the checkpoint using CRUI

```
// CheckpointCreate checkpoints the process running in a container with CRIU

func (daemon *Daemon) CheckpointCreate(name string, config types.CheckpointCreateOptions) error {
container, err := daemon.GetContainer(name)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if !container.IsRunning() {
    return fmt.Errorf("Container %s not running", name)
}

if container.Config.Tty {
    return fmt.Errorf("checkpoint not support on containers with tty")
}

if !validCheckpointNamePattern.MatchString(config.CheckpointID) {
    return fmt.Errorf("Invalid checkpoint ID (%s), only %s are allowed", config.CheckpointID, validCheckpointNameChars)
}

checkpointDir, err := getCheckpointDir(config.CheckpointDir, config.CheckpointID, name, container.ID, container.CheckpointDir(), true)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("cannot checkpoint container %s: %s", name, err)
}

err = daemon.containerd.CreateCheckpoint(context.Background(), container.ID, checkpointDir, config.Exit)
if err != nil {
    os.RemoveAll(checkpointDir)
    return fmt.Errorf("Cannot checkpoint container %s: %s", name, err)
}

daemon.LogContainerEvent(container, "checkpoint")

return nil
```

}

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/checkpoint.go

Comment: I came error when I do `make BIND_DIR=. shell`. The error message is :

`gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file`

So I wonder how can I re-make it. I didn't see `make clean` in its makefile.

Comment: No more errors. Your advice is really helpful to me.

Comment: You are welcome.... reach me here arif.ahmed@irisa.fr for further discussion on Docker container migration.